# What's the most concise cross-browser way to access an <iframe> element's window and document?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, cross-browser, document

I'm trying to figure out the best way to access an `<iframe>` element's `window` and `document` properties from a parent page. The `<iframe>` may be created via JavaScript or accessed via a reference stored in an object property or a variable, so, if I understand correctly, that rules out the use of `document.frames`.

I've seen this done a number of ways, but I'm unsure about the best approach. Given an `<iframe>` created in this way:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
```

I'm currently using this to access the `document`, and it seems to work OK across the major browsers:

```
var doc = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) {
  doc = doc.document;
}
```

I've also see this approach:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my_iframe');

iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow :
         (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document :
         iframe.contentDocument;

iframe.document.open();
iframe.document.write('Hello World!');
iframe.document.close();
```

That confuses me, since it seems that if `iframe.contentDocument.document` is defined, you're going to end up trying to access `iframe.contentDocument.document.document`.

There's also this:

```
var frame_ref = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

var iframe_doc = frame_ref.contentWindow ? frame_ref.contentWindow.document :
    frame_ref.contentDocument;
```

In the end, I guess I'm confused as to which properties hold which properties, whether `contentDocument` is equivalent to `document` or whether there is such a property as `contentDocument.document`, etc.

Can anyone point me to an accurate/timely reference on these properties, or give a quick briefing on how to efficiently access an `<iframe>`'s `window` and `document` properties in a cross-browser way (without the use of jQuery or other libraries)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12):

There's an easier way that's been around longer... use `window.frames` to get a reference to the frame's window object.

By name or id:

```
var iframe_doc = window.frames.my_iframe.document;
```

or if you prefer:

```
var iframe_doc = window.frames['my_iframe'].document;
```

or by index:

```
var iframe_doc = window.frames[0].document;
```

Good reference for `window.frames` here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frames

An excerpt:

> each item in the window.frames
>   pseudo-array represents the window
>   object corresponding to the given
>   <frame>'s or <iframe>'s content, not
>   the (i)frame DOM element (i.e.
>   window.frames[ 0 ] is the same thing
>   as document.getElementsByTagName(
>   "iframe" )[ 0 ].contentWindow)

Answer (score 12):

During the time I made many tests, and finally came up with this short but robust syntax which works on every browser I could test:

```
var doc = iframe.contentDocument ?
iframe.contentDocument : (iframe.contentWindow.document || iframe.document);
```

**EDIT:** @DaggNabbit noticed that a reference error in `iframe.contentWindow.document`, if `iframe.contentWindow` is not set, would block the code execution, not allowing `iframe.document` to be returned.
So I refined my code:

```
var doc = iframe.contentDocument ?
    iframe.contentDocument :
    (iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.document);
```

NOTE: `iframe.document` is a workaround for IE5.

Comment: The last part of this condition seems fishy. It assumes `iframe.contentWindow` exists by referencing a property of it. If it doesn't exist, it will throw a ReferenceError, and the `|| iframe.document` part will never execute. Even if `|| iframe.document` does execute, it probably won't do anything useful (assuming `iframe` is an iframe element, it won't have a `document` property unless someone stuck it there). Apparently [this would not work in Safari circa 2004](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.javascript/contentwindow-portable-alternative/153090). What's wrong with `frames`?

Comment: Also, the mixed use of a ternary and short-circuiting `||` operator makes this unnecessarily unwieldy. Above comment aside, why not just write `var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document || iframe.document;`?

Comment: @DaggNabbit thanks for your clarification: "_It assumes iframe.contentWindow exists by referencing a property of it_": no, it means that if `iframe.document` is not set, then `iframe.contentWindow.document` is. If you want to check the existence of the `contentWindow` property and its `document` sub-property, you may do that indeed, but my tests on different browsers shown that if `contentDocument` property is not set then `contentWindow` and `contentWindow.document` are.

Comment: My point was that `iframe.contentWindow.document || iframe.document` is not useful for two reasons: 1, iframe elements don't have a `document` property, and 2, `iframe.contentWindow.document` shouldn't ever evaluate to false. If iframes have a `contentWindow` window property then it will surely have a `document` property, but if they don't have `contentWindow` it will throw a ReferenceError, so `iframe.document` is never evaluated anyway. The whole thing could be written as `var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document`

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. Yes, if `iframe.contentWindow.document` is not set, then the reference error interrupts the execution and `iframe.document` would never got returned. There should be another ternary operator, I will correct my answer. Regarding `iframe.document`, it is not a standard, but allows the code to work in IE5 (you know how IE is tricky).

Comment: Are you sure `iframe.document` works in IE5? I can't find any record of it, but I did find people saying that only `window.frames` would work in that version of IE, [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=98572).

Comment: Sure mate, there are some libraries using this solution; for example scheduler.js; look at row 217: http://scheduler.cfunited.com/js/scheduler.js Cheers!

Comment: That code looks pretty sketchy to me... assigning values to undeclared variables, calling functions which don't exist (`addEvent`), dumping everything in the global scope. Honestly I'm not sure how that code can even work; I guess it must depend on some other code? Now I'm really curious about iframe.document in ie5, maybe I'll see if I can get it to run under wine or something.

Comment: Getting a demonstration of that code is an interest of mine, too! I hope I can reproduce the environment to test it, or, alternatively, finding useful information to clarify if it works or not in IE5. Just for confirmation that the normal known methods do not work, here's a test which states the solution does NOT work on IE5 (but works on IE5.5 and greater): http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/

Comment: Using some source code search engines I find various scripts using `document.getElementById('iframe').document`; try searching `iframe.document` on https://meanpath.com/ or http://code.ohloh.net/ I also tried https://search.nerdydata.com/ but it does not search for the exact string entered.

Comment: Hehe, I tried searching around too, but couldn't find anything. Even if it does work, I'd probably just stick to `window.frames` which has worked everywhere since the dawn of interwebs.

Answer (score 3):

all of the modern browsers except Chrome support both `iframereference.contentWindow` and `iframereference.contentDocument`, but only if the page opened in the iframe is on the same domain as the page containing the iframe.

To include Chrome, use `var iwin=iframereference.contentWindow,
idoc=iwin.document;`

`.contentDocument` is the `window.document` of the page in the iframe, 
as is `contentWindow.document`, but not `.contentDocument.document`.

Chrome may include support for `.contentDocument` in some future version- I hope so, because it is also the way all the other browsers find the document contained in an Object element, type `text/html`, where the data attribute is the url of an html page.

Comment: Thanks, kennebec! So, I did some testing keeping in mind your feedback. It actually looks like IE (at least IE 7) is the straggler on contentDocument; Chrome appeared to support it. Would `var win = iframe.contentWindow; var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;` be a sufficient and stable cross-browser (back to IE 6) check for the `window` and `document` objects?

Comment: The one-line solution I posted takes into account all these considerations :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a very easy and cross browser way

```
//get document object of IFRAME
if(typeof frame.contentDocument!='undefined') {
    iframeDocument=frame.contentDocument;
} else {
    iframeDocument=frame.document;
}
//get window object of IFRAME
if(typeof frame.contentWindow!='undefined') {
    iframeWindow=frame.contentWindow;
} else {
    iframeWindow=frame.window;
}
```

you can test it