# How to access ids found inside iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to access an id found inside an iframe.
I have the following code:

`print "<IFRAME id='preview_iframe_form' ...  src=\"$server_url/index.cgi ";`

Inside index.cgi, I have the following :

```
      print"<div id='result_div'>";
      &show_list();
      print "</div>";
```

I need to check the result_div height so set the  height of preview_iframe_form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947082/whats-the-most-concise-cross-browser-way-to-access-an-iframe-elements-window

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto-size an iFrame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247128/how-to-auto-size-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('preview_iframe_form');
var iframedoc = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.contentDocument;
var resultEl = iframedoc.getElementById('result_div');
```

Comment: Exactly where I shall try those? After the iframe? Or for the javascript code of index.cgi..

Comment: You would use this from the containing page, possibly from the onload event of the iframe.

Comment: You must have called it before the node was loaded. Make sure to call it after onload, or after the close body tag