# What's wrong with my Javascript If...else... function?

Tags: javascript, iframe, if-statement

I am currently building a website as part of my Media Coursework for Year 11 but I can't seem to get this If...Else... function to work. Here is my coding.

```
if(ifr.contentDocument.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_MessagesTextWrapper") != null){
    notify("Personalising site...")
    document.getElementById("loginButton").innerHTML = "Account Connected!";
    document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick=function(){window.location.href="//roblox.com/--place?id=91276386";}
    notify("Account connected successfully");
    hideWheel();
}else{
    notify("Could not connect account");
    hideWheel();
};
```

I removed the "if(...){...}else{...};" from the code and found it worked, so I'm sure that the fault is in the "if(...)" itself.

If it helps, ifr was actually created using document.createElement("iframe");
The iFrame does have a "src" and does show up on the page with the content displayed.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: is there an error shown in the console?

Comment: If the iframe loading an external URL, you cannot access its content.

Comment: Why are you putting `hideWheel()` in both conditional paths? Just put it outside the conditional if you want it to always run.

Comment: first check your browser console for javascript error. Am not sure the getElementById would understand those jargons. Just joking :)

Comment: There is an error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getElementById': object is null or undefined 
rbxLaunchSite.htm, line 33 character 1

Comment: @3659905 there is your answer. ifr.contentDocument.document or similar. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947082/whats-the-most-concise-cross-browser-way-to-access-an-iframe-elements-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphBanner_MenuRedesign_BannerAlertsAndOptionsLoginView_BannerAlertsAndOptions_Authenticated_MessagesTextWrapper");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);

if(y.document){

    notify("Personalising site...")
    document.getElementById("loginButton").innerHTML = "Account Connected!";
    document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick=function(){window.location.href="//roblox.com/--place?id=91276386";}
    notify("Account connected successfully");
    hideWheel();

}
else{

    notify("Could not connect account");
    hideWheel();

};
```

Is the iframe that you try to access and page from which you try to access on the same domain? If it is on another domain you can't access it because of cross domain blockade!

Also I am suprised by that long ID, is that ID correct?

Comment: No, the page that the iframe is trying to access is a games website. The ID is correct, they use very long IDs on most things (after inspecting their website).

Comment: If it is on another domain I am sorry to tell that you can't access it because of cross domain blockade :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

`ifr.contentWindow.document`

You can also refer to: [How can I access iframe elements with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript)