# Wrap the document or window object to check scroll value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window, document

To check the scroll values of the page I used to wrap the `window` object with jQuery, but when scrolling, the target element of the scroll event results to be the `document` object:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    alert('Scrolling ' + e.target);
});
```

What is the right object to wrap to check the scroll values?
I know the difference between them (a window can contain multiple frames thus many documents), but for a single document context I see the scroll values coincide:

```
alert($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).scrollTop());
```

**EDIT:**

It also happens with native JavaScript:

```
window.onscroll = function(e) { alert('scrolled ' + e.target); };
```

The element bound is `window`, but the event target is `document`.

About the expression written above, comparing the scrollTop value of the `window` object with the one of the `document` object: the jQuery documentation explains that `$(window).width()` returns the width of the viewport, while `$(document).width()` returns the width of the HTML DOM element; since the viewport may be smaller than the whole HTML element width, these two values may differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving jQuery aside for a moment, using plain JavaScript you can check the following properties of `window` for the current vertical scrolling position:

```
window.pageYOffset;
window.scrollY;
```

The second one is not cross-browser [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollY). Still according to that, on IE<9 you must check `document.body.scrollTop`, as no property of `window` will give you the current scroll position. Actually, `document.body.scrollTop` is what I use most  frequently, as in my experience it just works cross-browser (citation and checking needed here).

jQuery takes the browser differences into consideration, and grabs the right property from the right object regardless of which selector you use for `.scrollTop()` (take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js#l136-161)). In short, it doesn't matter if you select `window` or `document` with jQuery when asking for `.scrollTop()`. It will look for `window.pageYOffset`, and if it can't find it, it will return `document.body.scrollTop`.

---

A note about your comment on multiple documents per window: technically, each `window` object only points to a single `document`, and vice-versa. When you have multiple frames, there are separate `window` and `document` elements for each frame. For example, if you get a reference to a single iframe, you can get its own `window` and `document` from it:

```
// first iframe in main document
var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var ifrWindow = ifr.contentWindow;
var ifrDocument = ifrWindow.document; 
// The above is good for new and old browsers; 
// ifr.contentDocument is also available on modern browsers
```

Comment: In a window containing different frames each one has its own document, so this expression is always true: `window.frames[0].document !== window.frames[1].document;`. I accessed those documents from the same window object, this is what I meant.

Comment: Okay, that's basically what I'm saying. Maybe I didn't understand your question? Basically, it doesn't matter if you select `window` or `document` from jQuery when asking for `.scrollTop`. It will look for `window.pageYOffset`, and if it can't find it, it will return `document.body.scrollTop`.

Comment: Perfect, now I better understand your answer and the jQuery code behind the `scrollTop()` method, thanks for the plain explanation. In the lines above, I was showing that I accessed different document objects from the same window context, this is what I meant when I wrote _"a window can contain multiple frames thus many documents"_.

Comment: @EmanueleDelGrande Glad you got it! I also edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, I also understood your point about the one-to-one window to document correspondence; you affirm this: `window.frames[0].contentWindow !== window` (I worked a lot on the frames: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947082/whats-the-most-concise-cross-browser-way-to-access-an-iframe-elements-window/7672234#7672234>)