# iframe.contentDocument not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, getelementsbytagname

How to run this on IE8?

```
var innerdoc = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].contentDocument;
```

I can't use jQuery neither `getElementsById()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672234/2151050

Answer (score 1):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting), the `contentDocument` property is not supported in IE8.

To work around that, you could access `.contentWindow.document` instead:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2],
    innerDoc = null;

if (element.contentDocument) {
  innerDoc = element.contentDocument;
} 
else if (element.contentWindow) { // IE fallback
  innerDoc = element.contentWindow.document;
}
```