# Javascript top.frames is not working chrome

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with chrome compatibility. Below javascript function is not working for chrome.

```
function changeHeaderPage()
{
    window.top.frames["lcdbody"].document.retour("renaultLogo");
}
```

retour function is giving an "undefined" error in chrome. But it is working in Internet Explorer.

> **Error**: Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'retour' of undefined**
>
> ```
>       at changeHeaderPage (header.jsp:22)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (header.jsp:35)
> ```

Please provide the alternative for the `window.top.frames`
Which works in Both browsers.

Comment: Is "lcdbody" a `frame` or an `iframe`?

Comment: _“retour function is giving an "undefined" error in chrome.”_ - no, it’s not. Please learn to understand what error messages are actually trying to tell you. `window.top.frames["lcdbody"].document` - _that_ is what is undefined. And had you realized that, and done a bit of research, you could have found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947082/whats-the-most-concise-cross-browser-way-to-access-an-iframe-elements-window yourself.

Comment: And if `retour` is supposed to be a global function, then accessing it via `document` would have been wrong to begin with (if IE appears to do something “right”, that other browsers don’t - then you usually should search the mistake on _your_ end) - global functions are properties of the window object, not document.